# Expanding and collapsing table row (tr) using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, click, slidetoggle

[image]

I have a table with active and inactive items. This table is dynamically populated from database. I am trying to add a toggle for only inactive items in my table and display all active items. I mean I want to show all active items and slide toggle only inactive items in my table.

```
<div class="alertsList">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>time</th>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025973</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

$('.alertRow.InActive').Parent.click(function () {

    $(this).nextUntil('tr.td.InActive').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

[My Fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/3pakpw88/)

How can I do that..?

Comment: Just checking if you have considered a simpler (and slightly foolish) solution. Is it an option to handle these as two separate grids? Both working independently? That way, your toggle function will reduce to a hide and show kind of an operation. Active grid will always remain seen, and you hide and show the Inactive ones separately. All you need to make sure is that styles are applied so that column widths remain the same for both the grids. Apologies if this is too simplistic a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code to toggle the table rows which are "inactive". It's better to rely on "closest()" than "parent()" or "parents()", because it's faster and it makes more sense to use it in this case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Save all the inactive rows
  var inactive_rows = '';
  $('.InActive').closest("tr").each(function() {
    inactive_rows += '<tr class="alertRow">';
    inactive_rows += $(this).html();
    inactive_rows += '</tr>';
  });
  console.log(inactive_rows);
  // Save all the active rows
  var active_rows = "";
  $('.Active').closest("tr").each(function() {
    active_rows += '<tr class="alertRow">';
    active_rows += $(this).html();
    active_rows += '</tr>';
  });
  // Empty the table
  $('.alertsList').html("");
  // Load the new table
  var table_html = '<table width="100%"><thead><th></th><th>Id</th><th>From</th><th>Action</th><th>State</th><th>time</th></thead><tbody>';
  table_html += active_rows;
  table_html += inactive_rows;
  table_html += '</tbody></table><a href="" class="toggleInactiveRows">Toggle Inactive Rows</a>';
  $('.alertsList').append(table_html);

  // Hide the inactive rows when the page loads
  $('.InActive').closest("tr").hide();

  // Toggle the inactive rows
  $('.toggleInactiveRows').click(function() {
    $('.InActive').closest("tr").slideToggle();
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertsList">
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
      <th></th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>time</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="alertRow">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025973</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="" class="toggleInactiveRows">Toggle Inactive Rows</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance to Hide Inactive items by default and toggle them?

Comment: Here you go :) I edited the code above. Please mark this answer as valid if you feel it solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much but As per my diagram in question InActive items are separated as a block. I am also trying to group by InActive items as separate block and toggle them.

Comment: It's better to do that using a server-side scripting language (PHP, ASP.NET etc.). You'll sort the array properly and then you loop over the array. I edited the JavaScript code with a solution to the new problem, but it's better to do it using a server-side language.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, Jquery doesn't properly handle height animations on table elements, So we'll inject `<div>`'s inside the `<td>`'s to be animated, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/2333214).

Secondly, Since you want to toggle the inactive items as a group, We should group them together.

- We'll find the inactive rows using [`has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has) method, wrap them in a `<tfoot>` using [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall) and insert it before the `<tbody>`,
  for which we use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore).

  <sup>I'm using [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore) since it is the better practice due to the advantage mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054056/2333214). We can use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter) as well, since it is semantically okay to include the `<tfoot>` after the `<tbody>`,</sup>
- Then we [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) the `<td>`'s inside them and wrap their content in a hidden `<div>` using [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner) method.

  <sup>You can avoid this step by populating the table accordingly in serverside</sup>
- We then add the option for toggling [before](http://api.jquery.com/before) the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first) inactive row.
- [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) click of the toggle option, we use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to access it's parent `<tr>` and then [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) to target all the following `<tr>` - which are inactive. We then find the `<div`'s which we injected inside them and call [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle) for the toggle functionality.

  <sup>We can use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) as well for accessing the parent `<tr>` according to current markup. I'm using closest so that it'll work event if you bind the event handler to an element inside `<td>` - say for example, a button.</sup>

  <sup>We can use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) as well for accessing the following `<tr>`'s, since we separated the active and inactive rows into different containers.</sup>

  <sup>Note that we need to [delegate the event handler](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation) using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) since
  we're injecting the toggle option dynamically.</sup>
- Finally we use the CSS pseudo element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to display the
  corresponding icon based on a class, which is toggled when the user
  clicks the toggle option using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

Other than these,

- I've wrapped the title columns inside `<thead>` which is more
  semantically appropriate.
- I've set a minimum width for the `<td>` to avoid the "jerk" due to the change in width of `State` column when the visibility of all `Inactive` items are toggled
- I've removed the empty `<td>` and added some CSS for the sake of demo

---

We end up with the following *semantically cool* structure which is *collapsible*:

```
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
          <th> title</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Toggle Switch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div> Collapsible content</div></td>
     </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
          <td>body content</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```js
$('.alertRow').has(".InActive")
// group them together in a tfoot and insert it before tbody
         .insertBefore(".alertsList table tbody").wrapAll("<tfoot></tfoot>")
// inject the hidden divs inside the columns for animating
         .find("td").wrapInner("<div style='display:none'/>").end()
// insert the toggle option before the first inactive row
         .first().before("<tr><td class='toggle' colspan='5'> Inactive Items</td></tr>");

$(".alertsList table").on("click", ".toggle", function () {
   // following class keeps track of the cuurrent state
   $(this).toggleClass("expanded")
   // find all the injected divs and toggle them
      .closest("tr").nextAll("tr").find('td  div').slideToggle(700);
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
th,td{
  min-width:80px;
  text-align:center;
}
.toggle{
  background:dodgerblue;
}
.toggle::before{
    content:"+"
}
.toggle.expanded::before{
    content:"-"
}
tfoot tr{
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertsList">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="alertRow">
                <td>1025973</td>
                <td>SYSTEM</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td class="Active">Active</td>
                <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow">
                <td>1025974</td>
                <td>SYSTEM</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td class="Active">Active</td>
                <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow">
                <td>1025974</td>
                <td>SYSTEM</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow">
                <td>1025974</td>
                <td>SYSTEM</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow">
                <td>1025974</td>
                <td>SYSTEM</td>
                <td>false</td>
                <td class="Active">Active</td>
                <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wissam solution is what I am looking for, but your code is awesome and the way you explain is really useful. I am not sure how to add bonus points to your answer but have to add tick to Wissam for giving solution which I require.

Comment: @Chandana You can see the bonus point number below the votes aside every answer, clicking it will give the bonus points to that answer... :) BTW, if you don't do it manually, the accepted answer will get the bonus points when the bounty expires..

Answer (score 4):

You had a couple problems with your selectors:

```
$('.alertRow .InActive').parent().click(function () {
    $(this).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

This should work the way you intended.

Unfortunately, as far the animation of the slideToggle is concerned, tables tend to have a restricted style to them. In this case the slideToggle will not animate due to the line-height of the `tr` elements. You could set the `tr` `line-height` and `height` properties manually in the CSS, but it might cause you some other formatting pain in the future. Here's an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pakpw88/2/).

Comment: Toggle is little difficult as items are hidden on click. Could you please help me with tips how can I make active and inactive 2 blocks and toggle inactive items.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a previous post, you will need to set the `line-height` and `height` style properties of the `tr` tag for the animation effects to work.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3pakpw88/4/) is an example that toggles all 'InActive' rows using a button.

CSS:

```
tr {
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="alertsList">
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>time</th>
        <tr class="alertRow">
            <td></td>
            <td>1025973</td>
            <td>SYSTEM</td>
            <td>false</td>
            <td class="Active">Active</td>
            <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alertRow">
            <td></td>
            <td>1025974</td>
            <td>SYSTEM</td>
            <td>false</td>
            <td class="Active">Active</td>
            <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alertRow">
            <td></td>
            <td>1025974</td>
            <td>SYSTEM</td>
            <td>false</td>
            <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
            <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alertRow">
            <td></td>
            <td>1025974</td>
            <td>SYSTEM</td>
            <td>false</td>
            <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
            <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="alertRow">
            <td></td>
            <td>1025974</td>
            <td>SYSTEM</td>
            <td>false</td>
            <td class="Active">Active</td>
            <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btnShowHide" type="button" value="Show/hide" />
```

JS:

```
 $('#btnShowHide').click(function () {
    $('.InActive').parent('tr').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for this would be, Bind the data in a fashion that the active ones comes first and then the inactive ones (use sorting for the same).

If it is not possible, then probably you can use below code for sorting them (FYI this would work only for those elements which are already present in the DOM and should be run only once)

```
// a simple compare function, used by the sort below
var compare_rows = function(a, b) {
    var a_val = $(a).find('td.Active').text().toLowerCase();
    var b_val = $(b).find('td.InActive').text().toLowerCase();
    if (a_val > b_val) { return 1; }
    if (a_val < b_val) { return -1; }
    return 0;
};
// the actual sort
$('#tableID tr').sort(compare_rows).appendTo('#tableID');
```

Then add the Icon for collapsing and Expanding Hidden ones

```
$("<tr class='toggle'><td colspan='5'>Show Hidden Icons</td></tr>").insertBefore($($(".alertsList table tr td.InActive")[0]).parent())
```

At last, add the click even for the dynamic icon added as below,

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

As [T J said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26177756/86072), it is complicated to animate the height of a table row (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920480/2333214) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2092913/86072) for hacks around it, which involve wrapping each cell's content in a `<div>`).

You could skip the animation altogether, and simply hide or show the inactive rows :

```
$('#btnToggle').click(function() {
    $('td.InActive').closest('tr').toggle();
});
```

If you want some visual candy to signal the hiding to the user, I would suggest using `.fadeToggle()` which will work straight away :

```
$('#btnToggle').click(function() {
    $('td.InActive').closest('tr').fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pakpw88/6/)

---

As an extra note : if you can modify the code that generates the table (e.g. : the PHP or ruby (or wathever) code), try putting the `active / inactive` class on the *row* (the `<tr>` node) rather than the inner cell (the `<td>` node) :

```
<div class="alertsList">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>time</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow active">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow active">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow inactive">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow inactive">
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="alertRow active">
                ...
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This would make for easier rules in your css and js :

```
//css
tr.inactive {font-style: italic; background-color: #eee}

//js
$('tr.inactive').fadeToggle(1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

I create this using `fadeToggle`:

```js
$("table tr td.InActive").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().children(":not(:first-child)").hide();
});

$('a').click(function () {
    $(this).text() == "+" ? $(this).text("-") : $(this).text("+");
    $(this).parents("tr").children(":not(:first-child)").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertsList">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>time</th>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025973</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Aa you can see i added a +/- `a` element to show/hide inactive rows.